# Подскажите, что нужно дописать в регулярном выражении?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, re

У меня имеется словарь:

```
resul = {"SN":"SN: abc123\r\nMAC: 10:ab:cd:30:5C:7C\r\n01-04-2022 Замена"}
```

я написал в коде регулярное выражение:

```
name_match_3 = re.search(r'(\r\n.+)', test1.get('sn'), flags=re.DOTALL)
    dict_miner_regular['Comment'] = (name_match_3.group(1) if name_match_3 else None)
```

в итоге у меня получается:

```
result_2 = {'Comment':'MAC: 10:ab:cd:30:5C:7C\r\n01-04-2022 Замена'}
```

Но мне надо убрать и MAC: 10:ab:cd:30:5C:7C. Но он не везде есть.

в итоге надо, чтобы убралось SN: и MAC:

```
result_3 = {'Comment':'01-04-2022 Замена'}
```

я понимаю, что надо что-то дописать сюда --> (r'(\r\n.+)' ...

Comment: где у вас в словаре закрывающая ковычка? и зачем вам вообще регулярки, если можно обойтись без них?

Comment: исправил, но я не знаю как можно без них...

Comment: все равно у вас неправильный словарь. ключ SN - это что? переменная? если нет, почему не в кавычках?

Comment: SN: это ключ и внутри есть значение для SN: чтобы можно было брать

Answer (score 0):

делайте сплит по переводу строки и берите последний элемент этого сплита. и подставляйте куда вам нужно.

```
resul = {"SN":"SN: abc123\r\nMAC: 10:ab:cd:30:5C:7C\r\n01-04-2022 Замена"}
res = {}
res["Comment"] = resul["SN"].split("\n")[-1]
```

res:

```
{'Comment': '01-04-2022 Замена'}
```

Comment: Да она решила даную задачу но к сожалению она не подходит, по этому нужна регулярка так как данных может быть много в данном ключе

Comment: пример данных, для которых это решение не подходит приведите.

Comment: {"Comment": "SN: 0907000337\r\n21.04 22 - Error Code - 130- Сгорел  Отправлена \r\n26.04.22 Замена вента"}

или 

{"Comment": "SN: 0907000337\r\nMAC: C6-02-06-00-3C-D1\r\n21.04 22 - Error Code - 130- Сгорел  Отправлена \r\n26.04.22 Замена вента"}

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло вот это условие:
*(?:^|\r\n)((?:(?!SN|MAC|\r\n).)+)*

Answer (score 0):

Используйте

```
(?m)^(?!SN|MAC)[^\r\n]+
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/eB1lWG/3).

**Подробности**

- `(?m)` - многострочный режим включен
- `^` - начало строки
- `(?!SN|MAC)` - сразу после текущей позиции не должно быть ни `SN`, ни `MAC`
- `[^\r\n]+` - один и более символов, отличным от символов перевода строки LF / CR